# OmNet++ How can I implement my own routing algorithm for adhoc newtork simulation?

Tags: omnet++

I am using the INET framework to create an ad hoc network simulation. All the tutorials use Ipv4NetworkConfigurator module for the routing but I want to use my own algorithm. The algorithm will choose the paths based on delay and node lifetime. Here's the overview:

The source generates an RREQ packet. An RREQ contains the following information:

<SourceAddress, DestinationAddress, SequenceNumber,TraversedHopList, ThrDelay, PathDelay, ThrLife, MinLife>.

Here, ThrDelay represents the threshold on the allowable delay, PathDelay represents the delay of a path in which RREQ is being processed, ThrLife represents threshold on the path lifetime, MinLife represents the minimum of lifetimes of nodes along the path traversed in which RREQ is being processed. PathDelay is initialized to 0, and MinLife is initialized to a very large number at the source.

How can I add my code so that OmNet uses my algorithm instead of the algorithm provided by INET?

Answer (score 1):

You implement your routing algorithm as a module and then configure your network to use that using

```
*.*.routingApp.typename = "YourRoutingProtocol"
```

There is an extensive MANET showcase in the INET webpage that uses various mobile routing protocols.

https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/routing/manet/doc

You just implement your own variant and configure it according the showcase.